# Theme Appearance

Tags: themes, support

I cannot figure out why themes are not loading correctly on my website. I am pretty new to this but am trying to learn as much as I can. I have used Google but haven't figure out the solution.

Here is my problem: I have downloaded multiple themes from WordPress for use on my WordPress website, but every theme appears as basic HTML. So all the pictures, functionality, etc, do not appear. There is only one theme (Zerif-lite) that seems to work correctly, but every other theme simply looks like a wall of HTML text.

Anyone have any idea what's going on? I've read that it might be an issue linking the stylesheet.css to the correct folder? I am confused.

Comment: So long as you are applying a theme correctly (and it's a normal, well-built theme) it will link up with its own style.css ... in your case there's a whole host of 'whys' and 'hows' errors might be happening so you'll need to narrow things down for us. Make sure you've installed Wordpress properly. Make sure you apply a standard theme. Make sure you understand what you should be seeing vs what you are seeing. Where is your 'wall of html' and what does this look like? Try to be as specific as possible or the folks in here will eat you alive.

Comment: @MonkeyPuzzle I understand what I should and should not be seeing. I have other websites that I have created, all of which work fine, but for this one website it won't load correctly. Example: I downloaded a free theme through WordPress and installed it as I have with other themes previously, but I cannot customize it. I have tried a wide variety of themes and the same thing happens. Any theme with the Parallax feature seems to work, the rest don't. Example: I click 'customize' but nothing shows up, my website will only show my latest posts.

Answer (score 1):

> every theme appears as basic HTML. So all the pictures, functionality, etc, do not appear

When you visit any page which showcases a theme, or even check out the theme's preview image (*which is the image that shows up under the theme selection page in the back end*), you will see an image of the theme with a lot of demo content, the content you are referring to. The developer just uses that demo content (*which is his own content*) to showcase his theme in order to show you how the theme could look on the front end.

When the theme gets shipped, it is shipped without all of that demo content because, obviously, you will add your own content and that demo content belongs to the theme author. The basic functionality of the theme is still there, these does not get removed. You must just apply whatever the theme offers and add the correct content for your site to look like these demo images of the theme.

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply; I have other websites I have made and installed basic themes on (like Zerif-lite, AccessParallax, etc) and they normally install correctly with all the features and functionality that they showcase through their demo. However, now when I install a theme I get a blank wall for a homepage that will only show my latest posts. When I click 'customize' I am not able to edit anything except the 'featured image', this happens with every theme on the marketplace with the exception of themes that have the 'Parallax' feature.